# How to add eventHandlers to Widget added dynamicaly to a view using MVP

Tags: gwt, handler, mvp

I have a view which reprents the BreadCrumb of a website, I update the view by setting the crumbs like this

```
public void setCrumb(ArrayList<Crumb> crumbs) {
    content.clear();        
    for (int i=0;i<crumbs.size()-1; i++){   
        Anchor anchor = new Anchor(crumbs.get(i).getText()) 
            content.add(anchor);
        content.add(new InlineHTML("  >  "));
    }
    content.add(crumbs.get(crumbs.size()-1).getText());
}
```

Now, I want to add EventHandlers to every Anchor added. I could just set the handler in the for loop by doing something like `anchor.addClickHandler(...)` but I'am using MVP, so the view doesn't have to manage handlers... I guess. In the presenter I have access to the panel that has all the anchors.

My question is : How to access the anchors from the presenter and set the eventHandler ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an MVP environment, creating of UI elements and catching events should happen in the View and the View should then handle those events and call to the Presenter to take appropriate action, like so:

```
public void setCrumb(ArrayList<Crumb> crumbs) {
    content.clear();        
    for (int i=0;i<crumbs.size()-1; i++){   
        Anchor anchor = new Anchor(crumbs.get(i).getText());
        anchor.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                presenter.doSomethingAboutAnchorClicks(...);
            }
        }); 
        content.add(anchor);
        content.add(new InlineHTML("  >  "));
    }
    content.add(crumbs.get(crumbs.size()-1).getText());
}
```

And in the Presenter, you want to have a method `handleEvent(Event event)` that can consume the events, and a method that calls to the View to `setCrumb(crumbs)`. It sounds to me like you're looking at MVP as the same as MVC. The difference is that handling events is the job of the Controller in MVC, while that job belongs to the View in MVP. There are some great resources out there on MVP, and you should definitely check them out. For basics, you can see the [Wikipedia Article: Model-View-Presenter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-presenter), which also contains references to several other great resources.

EDIT: here's some code from my personal use case, which is quite similar. This all happens in the View, based on a `regionReportElement` provided by the Presenter.

```
private Map<String, Anchor> breadCrumbs = new TreeMap<String, Anchor>();
private Map<String, ReportElement> reportElements = new TreeMap<String, ReportElement>();
// .... other stuff ...
@Override
public void addReportElement(final ReportElement reportElement) {
    Anchor anchor = new Anchor(reportElement.getShortName());
    anchor.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            presenter.onReportElementSelect(reportElement.getId());
        }
    });

    reportElements.put(reportElement.getId(), reportElement);
    if (breadCrumbs.get(reportElement.getId()) == null) {       
        breadCrumbs.put(reportElement.getId(), anchor);
        if (breadCrumbs.size() > 0) {
            breadCrumbContainer.add(new Label(" > "));
        }
        breadCrumbContainer.add(anchor);
    }
}
// .... other stuff ...
```

Comment: In this http://code.google.com/intl/fr-FR/webtoolkit/articles/mvp-architecture.html#presenter, the presenter get the widget from the display and add handler to it. But I guess passing the presenter to the view and then calling the methode that handles the event could be a varient...especially in this case when the widgets are created dynamicaly .

Comment: @Moh I have the exact same use case as you show here where breadcrumbs are dynamically created, only displaying Regions instead of website breadcrumbs. I'm attaching my own version of the code to my answer, maybe it will help you.

Comment: As you'll notice in my code, I use Map objects to keep things clean and be sure everything is only added once. Since my breadcrumbs can get very deep, this is a must.